# SFTP Permision error

Tags: ftp, sftp

I just set up Batami Magento for the Google Cloud platform. Using the documentation given, I was able to successful set up my SFTP (Filezilla) using shh .ppk file. I have permission to upload my files to the default folder it took me to `/home/bitnami`. But I'm unable to upload or change permission of folder `/opt/bitnami/apps/magento` `/opt/bitnami/apps/magento`

here is the filezilla log

```
Status: Starting upload of C:\Users\GLOBEAST\Downloads\porto_2002\Porto 2.0.0.2\Theme Files\Magento 2.x\Porto Theme.zip
Command:    cd "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento"
Response:   New directory is: "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento"
Command:    put "C:\Users\GLOBEAST\Downloads\porto_2002\Porto 2.0.0.2\Theme Files\Magento 2.x\Porto Theme.zip" "Porto Theme.zip"
Error:  /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/Porto Theme.zip: open for write: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed
Status: Starting upload of C:\Users\GLOBEAST\Downloads\porto_2002\Porto 2.0.0.2\Theme Files\Magento 2.x\Porto Theme.zip
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento"...
Status: Listing directory /opt/bitnami/apps/magento
Command:    put "C:\Users\GLOBEAST\Downloads\porto_2002\Porto 2.0.0.2\Theme Files\Magento 2.x\Porto Theme.zip" "Porto Theme.zip"
Error:  /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/Porto Theme.zip: open for write: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed
Status: Starting upload of C:\Users\GLOBEAST\Downloads\porto_2002\Porto 2.0.0.2\Theme Files\Magento 2.x\Porto Theme.zip
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento"...
Status: Listing directory /opt/bitnami/apps/magento
Command:    put "C:\Users\GLOBEAST\Downloads\porto_2002\Porto 2.0.0.2\Theme Files\Magento 2.x\Porto Theme.zip" "Porto Theme.zip"
Error:  /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/Porto Theme.zip: open for write: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento"...
Status: Listing directory /opt/bitnami/apps/magento
Status: Directory listing of "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento" successful
Status: Set permissions of '/opt/bitnami/apps/magento' to '757'
Command:    cd "/opt/bitnami/apps"
Response:   New directory is: "/opt/bitnami/apps"
Command:    chmod 757 "magento"
Error:  set attrs for /opt/bitnami/apps/magento: permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami developer here,

By default, the `/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/` user and group are `root:root`, so `bitnami` does not have permissions there. The path  `/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/` has user and group `bitnami:daemon`. You should be able to upload files to this folder without any issue.

However, if you want to change the folder privileges, you need to access via SSH and execute `sudo chmod YOUR_FOLDER`. Note that it could produce security issues. For example, it's not recommended that `other users` have more privileges that `group` (as you would set using `chmod 757`).

I hope it helps